# What is a fixed-point theorem?

Tags: fixed-point-theorem

It is said that Cantor's diagonal argument is a special case of a fixed-point theorem. It is also said that the concept of recursion was shown to be expressible by Kleene, I believe, as a sort of "fixed point" phenomenon. What are fixed-point theorems?

Comment: [Y](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator#Y_combinator)

Comment: Yes, cantor's problem, halting, incompleteness theorems are all corollaries of lawveres fixed point theorem. Here is a helpful paper: https://www.uibk.ac.at/mathematik/algebra/staff/fritz-tobias/ct2021_course_projects/lawvere.pdf. a fixed point theorem is exactly that: a theorem stating for some function f that there is some x such that fx = x.  In logic, fixed points can be seen as "solutions" to "defining equations"

Comment: Philosophically speaking a fixed point is just an unmoved mover free from any spacetime or other metric constraints, since it's unmoved after any moving it can continue the same move recursively until the said move's destiny arrives which could be said to be delicately connected to Roger's, Kleene's recursion theorems and the more celebrated diagonal lemma..

Comment: See [Fixed-point theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_theorem): In mathematics, a fixed-point theorem is a result saying that a function F will have at least one point x for which F(x) = x, under some conditions on F that can be stated in general terms.

Comment: Regarding [Kleene's result](ttps://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene%27s_recursion_theorem) proved in 1952, it shows that the recursion theorem (of computability theory) can be applied to construct fixed points of certain operations on computable functions.

Answer (score 0):

You probably mean [Lawvere's fixed point theorem](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Lawvere%27s+fixed+point+theorem) of which many diagonal arguments (like Cantor's theorem, Russell's paradox, Gödel's incompleteness theorem etc.) are special cases.